# PHP/ Javascript inserting html with ' and " to a javascript function from PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, escaping

I have HTML in a database which I want to show with facebox (jquery popup).
I use the PHP code below to render the button that launches the facebox

```
$html.="<img onclick='$.facebox(\"".$db_data[html]."\");' src='img.png' />";
```

How can I escape things properly so that facebox will get also ' and " in $db_data[html]?
(for example if the html includes styles?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) to convert the string properly to a JavaScript compatible string and [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to encode it for the use in an HTML attribute value:

```
"<img onclick='" . htmlspecialchars("$.facebox(".json_encode($db_data['html']).");", ENT_QUOTES) . "' src='img.png' />"
```

Note the use of the quote style *ENT_QUOTES* to also encode `'` that are used to quote the attribute value. This wouldn’t be necessary if you would use `"` for the HTML attribute value instead:

```
'<img onclick="' . htmlspecialchars("$.facebox(".json_encode($db_data['html']).");") . '" src="img.png" />'
```